# Is there an in-app statistics library or service?

Tags: android, web-services, statistics

I'm developing a game for Android and I'd like to collect statistics on how users play the game: how many times they replay the level, what is kill/death ratio, how many times they miss the target and so on. Let's assume, I already have code for collecting needed data inside my application (so logic of counting stuff is defined). Now I want to pack the information and send it—at least to my email, at best to some web-service—to analyze it.

Any suggestions on that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Google Analytics SDK for Android](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html) to track how many users use your app. Also, you can track events with this SDK.

**UPDATE**

Actually, [Flurry Analytics](http://flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) might be even more suited for you. And its also free. Click on Custom Events and Parameters for details.

Answer (score 2):

There are several Android Analytics services:

Claritics, Flurry, Google Analytics, InApp, Localytics, Medialets and Mixpanel.

Those are the ones I found when scouting for them.